# Cannot remove scroll bars - overflow

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, overflow

Good afternoon all, Any help would be much appreciated.

I cant seem to get this right, the container isnt working the way id like it. i cant get rid of the scroll bars after having put overflow in,[image] i cant seem to get rid of the scroll bars! and center my profiles.  Thankyou!!! have been trying overflow: hidden; but cant get it right.

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);

html{
background:#d7d7d9;
 }

 *, html, body {
font-family: Open Sans;
}

ul, li {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style-type: none;
}

.profile-container{
 margin: 0px auto 0;
 width: 143px;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.profile{
 border-radius: 3px;
 -o-border-radius: 3px;
 -ms-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;  
  background:white;
 padding:4px;
  overflow: hidden;
  }

     .avatar img{
        border-radius: 3px;
      -o-border-radius: 3px;
        -ms-border-radius: 3px;
      -moz-border-radius: 3px;
         -webkit-border-radius: 3px; 
          }

      .follow button{
          background:#268cde;
       border-radius:3px;
      border:0;
        width:100%;
        margin:0;
         padding:7px 0;
        color:white;
       cursor: pointer;
           }

         .follow button i {
       font-size: 10px;
    color: #b9daf4;
       }

     .profile-list{
         width:100%;
      color: #767b7e;
   font-size: 13px;
  border-radius:0 0 3px 3px;
  }
     .profile-list li{
 -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
     -o-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
   transform-origin: 50% 0%;  
   -webkit-transform:perspective(250px) rotateX(-90deg);
  -moz-transform:perspective(250px) rotateX(-90deg);
  transform:perspective(250px) rotateX(-90deg);
   background:white;
   text-align:left;
   padding:15px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
    border-top:1px solid #d7d7d9;
   }

  .profile-list li i{
    padding-right:3px;
  }
.profile-list li.first{
 -webkit-transition: .2s linear 1.5s;
 -moz-transition: .2s linear 1.5s;
 transition: .2s linear 1.5s;
}
.profile-list li.second{
  -webkit-transition: .3s linear 1.2s;
  -moz-transition: .3s linear 1.2s;
  transition: .3s linear 1.2s;
}
 .profile-list li.third{
 -webkit-transition: .4s linear .8s;
 -moz-transition: .4s linear .8s;
  transition: .4s linear .8s;
}
 .profile-list li.fourth{
  -webkit-transition: .6s linear .2s;
  -moz-transition: .6s linear .2s;
  transition: .6s linear .2s;
 }
  .profile-container:hover .profile{
  border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
  -o-border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
   -ms-border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
   -moz-border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
   -webkit-border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
  }
  .profile-container:hover li{
  -webkit-transform:perspective(250px) rotateX(0deg);
   -moz-transform:perspective(250px) rotateX(0deg);
   transform:perspective(250px) rotateX(0deg);
  }
  .profile-container:hover li.first{
   -webkit-transition: .2s linear .2s;
   -moz-transition: .2s linear .2s;
   transition: .2s linear .2s;
  }
 .profile-container:hover li.second{
   -webkit-transition: .3s linear .4s;
   -moz-transition: .3s linear .4s;
   transition: .3s linear .4s;
  }
  .profile-container:hover li.third{
   -webkit-transition: .4s linear .7s;
   -moz-transition: .4s linear .7s;
   transition: .4s linear .7s;
  }
  .profile-container:hover li.fourth{
   -webkit-transition: .6s linear 1.1s;
    -moz-transition: .6s linear 1.1s;
    transition: .6s linear 1.1s;
   }
```

thankyou

Comment: Would be good to see the HTML. Please put it into a jsfiddle

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/limtu/yyxuf3pv/

Comment: It works perfect in chrome no scroll bars

Comment: ah ok, must be something on my end. when i try and sit them next to eachother they create scrollers. ah! Thankyou though!!!

Comment: put them in a container div and say overflow none. or only on the x-axis

Comment: Thanks so much andrew - it was actually a conflict with another .container div, Thank you very much for your help.